# Rotating ImageView using UIPanGestureRecognizer- Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to rotate an ImageView I have depending on the X coordinate it is on. Basically, I want it to have a rotation of 0º when x = 300 and a rotation of 180º when x = 190.

I had to program the UIPanGestureRecognizer programmatically. Here is the code I currently have right now:

```
    @objc func personDrag(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let rotationSub: CGFloat = 1

    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: rView)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x +  translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi - rotationSub)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: rView)

}
```

I was going to attempt to change the rotation degree by 1 every time they panned but it doesn't really work/make sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Cheers, Theo

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: @dmorrow it just spins super quickly when i move the imageview across the screen instead of changing the rotation degree depending on the x coordinate. does this clarify? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can build your implementation on this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!

    private var currentRotation: Rotation = .none

    /* Certain rotation points (rotation of 0º when x = 300 and a rotation of 180º when x = 190) */
    enum Rotation {
        case none, xPoint190, xPoint300
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        imageview.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        imageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed else {
            return
        }

        guard let imgView = gestureRecognizer.view else {
            return
        }

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        imgView.center = CGPoint(x: imgView.center.x + translation.x, y: imgView.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

        let angle: CGFloat = self.degreesToRadians(180.0)

        /* After reaching x point case - rotating and setting rotation occured to prohibit further rotation */

        if imgView.layer.frame.origin.x <= 190, currentRotation != .xPoint190 {

        imgView.transform = imgView.transform.rotated(by: angle)
        currentRotation = .xPoint190

    } else if imgView.layer.frame.origin.x >= 300, currentRotation != .xPoint300 {

        imgView.transform = imgView.transform.rotated(by: angle)
        currentRotation = .xPoint300
    }


    private func degreesToRadians(_ deg: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return deg * CGFloat.pi / 180
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you are confused. i would like the image to rotate as i drag it across the screen.

Comment: @TheoStrauss edited my answer. Implemented the dragging, when image view reaches certain x points it rotates. Hope it's what you want ;]

Comment: oh my god this is awesome. i need some time to digest and implement and ill check back with you. ill give u the check mark for now!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions ;)

Comment: hmm. it gives me the error that it doesn't recognize gestureRecognizer. Is that bc there is a guard? Could you help me out with this?

Comment: @TheoStrauss upload a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138747/discussion-between-oleh-zayats-and-theo-strauss).

Comment: Its not working properly and second thing after rotation pan gesture for movng that image is working invert. Left move going to right and right going to left

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
 @objc func rotateViewPanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: superview)
            let center = CGRectGetCenter(frame)

            switch recognizer.state {
            case .began:
                deltaAngle = atan2(touchLocation!.y - center.y, touchLocation!.x - center.x) - CGAffineTrasformGetAngle(transform)
                initialBounds = bounds
                initialDistance = CGpointGetDistance(center, point2: touchLocation!)

            case .changed:

                let ang = atan2(touchLocation!.y - center.y, touchLocation!.x - center.x)
                let angleDiff = deltaAngle! - ang

                let a = transform.a
                let b = transform.b
                let c = transform.c
                let d = transform.d

                let sx = sqrt(a * a + b * b)
                let sy = sqrt(c * c + d * d)

                let currentScale = CGPoint(x: sx, y: sy)
                let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: currentScale.x, y: currentScale.y)
                self.transform = scale.rotated(by: -angleDiff)

                layoutIfNeeded()
            case .ended:

              print("end gesture status")
            default:break

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift5

Programmatically

Rotate view by single point touch

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //Variable for rotating
    private var deltaAngle:CGFloat = 0
    
    let squareView : UIView = {
        let anyView = UIView()
        anyView.backgroundColor = .red
        anyView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        anyView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        return anyView
        
    }()
    
    let rotateButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "rotate.right"), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        squareView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
        rotateButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: squareView.frame.height-30, width: 30, height: 30)
        squareView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(squareView)
        squareView.addSubview(rotateButton)
        
        let PanToRotate = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotateGesture(_:)))
        rotateButton.addGestureRecognizer(PanToRotate)
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    @objc func handleRotateGesture(_ recognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: squareView.superview)
        
        let center = squareView.center
        
        switch recognizer.state{
            
        case .began :
            self.deltaAngle = atan2(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x) - atan2(squareView.transform.b, squareView.transform.a)
            
        case .changed:
            let angle = atan2(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x)
            
            let angleDiff = self.deltaAngle - angle
            
            squareView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -angleDiff)
                        
        default: break
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```